# Стандартное меню в 1С БИТРИКС

Tags: php, битрикс, меню, компоненты

Здравствуйте!

Разбираюсь со стандартным шаблоном горизонтального меню БИТРИКС.
В нем присутствует вот такой код проверки уровня вложенности текущего и предыдущего пункта меню:

```
<?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
<?= str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"])); ?>
<? endif ?>
```

Если проверка выполняется, то закрываются открытые теги списка.
Но никак не могу понять, зачем сравнивать 2 раза? То есть текущий уровень сравнивается с предыдущим, мы получаем либо true,либо false и дальше опять сравнивается, с помощью &&.
Все прекрасно работает, если написать просто:

```
<?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В php `if ($previousLevel)` тоже самое что и `if(!empty($previousLevel))`, но первый вариант более краток. 
Это условие просто проверяет существует ли $previousLevel и не пустая ли она, чтобы потом дальше при обращении к ней не было исключений ну или ворнингов, че там в php вылазиет не помню точно.

То есть,

> Все прекрасно работает, если написать просто:
>
> ```
> <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
> ```

до того момента пока не встретился случай когда `$previousLevel` равна `null`